# The order of execution for the 'HAVING' clause, without 'GROUP BY' in MySQL

Tags: mysql, having

I understand that since the `WHERE` clause is executed before the `SELECT`, the following query in MySQL 5 returns an Unknown column error:

```
SELECT id, 
    CASE 
        WHEN LENGTH(TRIM(middle_name)) > 0 THEN 
            CONCAT(first_name, ' ', LEFT (middle_name, 1), '. ', last_name) 
        ELSE CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name) 
    END AS name  
FROM people_table 
WHERE LENGTH(name) < 11;
```

But using the `HAVING` clause works:

```
SELECT id, 
    CASE 
        WHEN LENGTH(TRIM(middle_name)) > 0 THEN 
            CONCAT(first_name, ' ', LEFT (middle_name, 1), '. ', last_name) 
        ELSE CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name) 
    END AS name  
FROM people_table 
HAVING LENGTH(name) < 11;
```

So is the `HAVING` executed after `SELECT`, when there is no `GROUP BY`?

Also I tried in PostgresSQL. Then it looks like that `HAVING` without `GROUP BY` here is not allowed. But PostgresSQL does not care about the order of `WHERE` so the following query works:

```
SELECT id, 
    CASE 
        WHEN LENGTH(TRIM(middle_name)) > 0 THEN 
            first_name || ' '|| LEFT(middle_name, 1) || '. '|| last_name 
        ELSE first_name || ' '|| last_name 
    END AS name  
FROM people_table 
WHERE LENGTH(name) < 11;
```

Comment: For to understand how the server processes the query with HAVING but without GROUP BY you may add fake GROUP BY which treates each separate row as separate group - in your case this can be grouping by primary key column (add `GROUP BY people_table.id`). But if your query contains aggregate function then, backward, you'd add GROUP BY whitch treates all rows as one group (add `GROUP BY 1`).

Comment: Thank you Akina! The example of comparing `GROUP BY id` and `GROUP BY 1` is very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation for the [SELECT statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html), the ability to refer to the SELECT list from HAVING is supported as a non-standard extension to the SQL standard. This shows that HAVING is executed after *some parts* of the SELECT list by design.

> The SQL standard requires that HAVING must reference only columns in the GROUP BY clause or columns used in aggregate functions. **However, MySQL supports an extension to this behavior, and permits HAVING to refer to columns in the SELECT list and columns in outer subqueries as well**.

However, [window functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-usage.html) can be included in the SELECT list and these are documented as being executed *after* HAVING.

> Window functions are permitted only in the select list and ORDER BY clause. Query result rows are determined from the FROM clause, **after WHERE, GROUP BY, and HAVING processing**, and windowing execution occurs before ORDER BY, LIMIT, and SELECT DISTINCT.

The answer is that HAVING can be executed after some parts of the SELECT list and before other parts of the SELECT list.

Comment: Thank you Don! Now I see this is just MySQL only.

Comment: *This suggests that HAVING is executed after the SELECT list by design* This is true only partially. If output list contains window functions in some output columns expressions then these expressions are evaluated after HAVING clause evaluation.